# How to exit python console if condition does not satisfies

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, if-statement, passwords

I want to input an integer as a password from the user and if password does not match, the python console should close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exit() command can help. Refer the code below:

```
password = int(input())
your_password = 123
if password!=your_password:   #match the password
    exit()          #exit if password does not match
print("Welcome")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) functionality from the `sys` module.

Generally a non-zero exit is used to let the caller of the service know that the program exited with failures.

```
import sys
if notValid(password):
    sys.exit(1)
```